# Language option translation best practice

Tags: usability, web-app, language, internationalisation

Which provides better UX for a dropdown displaying user language options?

- Using **natural** or **current** language?
- Sorting by most popular, most recent, alphabetized, region?

### *natural* *(target)* language

- English (United States)
- Français (Canada)
- Español (Estados Unidos)
- 日本語 (日本)

### *current* language

- English (United States)
- French (Canada)
- Spanish (United States)
- Japanese (Japan)

such that they translate

- Anglais (États Unis)
- Français (Canada)
- Espanol (États Unis)
- Japonais (Japon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural language. If I can't read English, I also can't read "Spanish" in English.

Ordering depends on context. Some sites have a landing page with regional links, then it would make sense to copy those categories. Alphabetical is a good default. Most default/recent are likely too complex to be interpreted for what they are if the list is long and provide little benefit if you don't have to scroll.

Potentially have 1 or 2 'official' languages pinned to the top if you have many options. So for a chinese factory: Chinese, English | Dutch, French, German, Greek, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Russian, Spanish, Turkish, Vietnamese.

If you have different categories always indicate separation with something like a horizontal rule!

Comment: 2nd using the target  (natural) language. Accidentally flipped a handheld game console into Japanese and had no idea which of the (to me) list of meaningless squiggles meant "_English_". I would, however, go with keeping the recently used options at the top (I suspect most people regularly changing languages won't use more than the same two or possibly three).

Comment: I agree, for example see https://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/